# Как подключиться удалено к прокси на Rasberry pi?

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, proxy, raspberry-pi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Схема подключения.**

Задача удалено подключиться к прокси на расбери с выходом в интернет через USB модем (мегафон).

На расбери стоит прокси сервер с выходом в интернет через USB модем (мегафон)

Через ноутбук подключенный к домашнему wifi с прописанным в браузере прокси - все работает, сижу в интернете через мегафон. Параллельно с эти работает и домашний интернет "акадо". Внутри сети работает все как надо. Проблема в том что когда я пытаюсь подключиться удалено - не получается.

Поскольку на "Акадо" нет статического IP - пользуюсь DDNS (noip), проверял работает. На роутере стоит переброска порта.
Методом проб и ошибок пришел к выводу что у меня получается дойти до прокси удалено но обратный ответ в расбери теряется и скорей всего выходит не туда. Если отключить USB модем, тогда получается войти в SSH расбери удалено. Как только вставляю USB модем - расбери автоматически подключает интерет мегафон и доступ к SSH прерывается. Не могу понять что мешает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

конфигурационный файл 3proxy на расбери
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вывод команды route на расбери
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

настройки роутера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За картинку к вопросу прям респект :)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь похоже все не очень сложно.

При подключении `PI`  черзе модем в качестве `default gateway` для `PI` вы имеете модем (а вернее тот интерфейс).

Зная основы маршрутизации вы знаете что все пакеты, приходящие с `ip` не принадлежащим ни одной из сети (подсети) какого либо интерфейса и не относящиеся к какой либо записи в таблице маршрутизации отправляются как раз в `default gateway`.

При пробросе порта роутером - `PI` видит в приходящих пакетах оригинальные адреса источников.

`NoteBook.srcIp-->router.dnat-->(NoteBook.srcIp)-->PI--> Modem (default route)`

Если посмотреть на то что я попытался изобразить, вы вероятно увидете что `PI` видит именно тот `ip` источника и согласно своей таблице маршрутизации отправляет ответ именно в `default route` и поступает правильно.

Ваша задача сделать так чтобы `PI` принимая запросы на прокси отправляло именно туда, куда нужно, т.е. назад на роутер.

Теперь решение вопроса. На самом деле можно придумать несколько, но в данной ситуации я бы порекомендовал реализовать самый простой путь, а именно окромя "проброса порта" на роутере нужно сделать еще `nat` во внутреннюю сеть для данных пакетов чтобы `PI` видел эти пакеты как приходящие от роутера. Т.е. смотрите, схема примерно должна быт тогда такая  -

`NoteBook.srcIp-->router.dnat->(srcnat)-->(routerIP)-->PI-->NoteBook-->router` 
Не уверен что все понятно, но словами это происходит так - 
Ваш Роутер получает пакет, в таблице `PREROUTING` смотрит порт, видит что то порт прокси и прокидывает его на `ip` вашего `PI`, уже в таблице `POSTROUTING` согласно правилам которые вы напишете натит  запрос.

Ваш `PI` в этом случае получает этот пакет и для `PI` этот пакет от роутера, он его обрабатывает и оптправляет согласно таблице маршрутизации роутеру и там процесс идет дальше.

Теперь в нескольких словах ответ - вам нужно сделать nat внутрь вашей сети.  :)
А вот позволяет ли ваш роутер это сделать, тут я уж не знаю.